# DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_name PRESERVE TABLE deletes rows in prebuilt table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a materialized view on top of a prebuilt table. 
Now I want to only drop that materialized view layer and preserve the underlying table.

I attempted to use PRESERVE TABLE clause from the information in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8020.htm), but it still deletes all the rows and returns only the template of the table after deleting the materialized view layer.

This is the script I ran:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY AS 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_ORIGINAL
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH SYSDATE+0 NEXT SYSDATE+1/24
ON PREBUILT TABLE AS ( ... );

DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY 
PRESERVE TABLE;

SELECT * 
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY;
```

From the last select statement, I get an empty table template with no rows. The TABLE_ORIGINAL was not empty.

- Why do I get this result?
- How can I fix the query to preserve the original data from the TABLE_ORIGINAL?

**EDIT**

So upon some testing, I found out that this only happens when I create the mv with this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH SYSDATE+0 NEXT SYSDATE+1/24
ON PREBUILT TABLE AS ( ... );
```

But this is fine:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SCHEMA.TABLE_COPY
ON PREBUILT TABLE AS ( ... );
```

So the following question would be why does this happen? And again, how could I fix this to do what I want?

Comment: Have you verified there is data in TABLE_COPY before you drop the view?

Comment: @Russ Yup, I did a SELECT * FROM TABLE_COPY to verify that it held the data after creating the table itself and after creating its mv.